# Как в Pascal перевести число в строку?

Tags: pascal

Как в Pascal перевести число в строку?

Answer (score 5):

```
var
  s:string;
  i:integer;

begin
  i:=5;
  str(i,s);
  write(s);
end.
```

Comment: причем здесь синтаксис?

Answer (score 1):

```
{Str.PAS}

{ Пример программы для процедуры Str }

Function IntToStr(I : Longint) : String;
{ Преобразовывает значение типа Integer в строку }
Var S : String [11];
Begin
 Str(I, S);
 IntToStr:=S;
End;

Begin
 WriteLn(IntToStr(-5322)); { '-5332' }
End.
```

http://netsoftware.ucoz.ru/blog/kak_perevesti_chislo_v_tip_stroka_v_pascal_ili_inttostr_i_longint/2012-05-14-2